# Views contextual filter navigation links?

Tags: 7, views

Assuming a view with a contextual filter based on a field "category" that is a select list with a limited number of values: what is the best approach to *dynamically* generate a simple list of links (based on available values) at the top of the view to allow a user to navigate the categories? I want to expose the values as links and keep the clean url structure that contextual filters create. See screen below for reference.

In the past, I've hacked together a basic hard-coded solution using hook_views_pre_render and the l() function, but I'm wondering what the best practice would be.

[image: contextual filter navigation links]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [quicktabs](https://drupal.org/project/quicktabs) module. It should let you define "tabs" for these filters.

> The Quick Tabs module allows you to create blocks of tabbed content,
>   specifically views, blocks, nodes* and other quicktabs*. You can
>   create a block on your site containing multiple tabs with
>   corresponding content. Clicking on the tabs makes the corresponding
>   content display instantly, using jQuery.

Additionaly, there is this [in-depth blog post not written by me showing filtering/sorting a complex view + filters page using quicktabs](http://www.cmsquickstart.com/blog/tutorial-build-tabbed-searchsort-filter-drupal-7). The left side of this view page has "tabbed" items like what you want in your example. CSS tweaks will make the tabs "look" how you want.

Comment: + 1 for good useful info (and possibly a better solution that what I've outlined) but it's not quite what I want. I'm looking for a *dynamic* solution where the values available in the contextual filter field are automatically retrieved and formatted as links that add a filter value to the url.

Comment: the hooks in views lets you alter stuff -- I would still use Views and QuickTabs; then make an admin form that overrides the filter values. I'm not aware of any solution for *dynamic* content like you've listed. You could use a content type and rabbit hole and a nodequeue for your filter items; with a hook_views_pre_view() override to be all user-friendly. But all those dependencies made me throw up just now. :D

Comment: :) Thinking about this again today made me wonder about using taxonomy instead of a regular field for categories. Then, getting a list of tags/links would be trivial, I think. But I don't want the link to go a taxonomy display page, I want it to insert a contextual filter to the original view. Taxonomy always frustrates me because I feel like it adds a lot of stuff I don't really want.